# Azure Data Science VM Transfer File

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, jupyterhub

I am trying to transfer files between azure data science VM Jupyterhub and local computer. Normally I can make it manually but I need to do it automatically.
The idea is uplaod images to Azure- use their GPU and download results.

I tried to use this code from Microsoft tutorial but getting error like **the file doesn't exist**:

`scp ~/.azure/config azureuser@myserver.eastus.cloudapp.com:/home/azureuser/config`

Microsoft tutorial:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/copy-files-to-linux-vm-using-scp

Manually:
[image]

Comment: The command is no problem. And the error shows the file doesn't exist. Do you check that?

Comment: @CharlesXu You are right, I made a mistake and now it works fine. But I can not run the same code on virtual machine. It gives "the file doesn't exist". Do you think it is about my company network?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to copy the file from the local machine to the VM through the command `scp` in the VM?

Comment: Yes exactly. When I try to copy files from (or to) vm, I am getting permission error. I type my local machine's password but getting permission error.

Comment: Well, if you want to copy files to the VM through the command inside the VM, then your local machine needs to be accessible from the Internet via the right port. And you need to take care of which password you need to input.

Comment: I have internet access, I try to access with this address: user_name@localhost  --> Is it not correct way? I also tried user_name@ip_address but doesn't work.
What do you mean which password? Is it not the same password for windows?

Comment: If you are in the VM, you need to use the public IP of your local machine, not the localhost. When you are in your local machine, you just need to use the path, without the localhost.

Comment: For example, you are on the local machine. You just need to execute the command `scp /path/file username@vm_publicIp:/destination_path/`. And the destination path must be the home path of the username you used.

Comment: I can transfer files on my computer without any problem. But when I try on VM it gives this error: "ssh: connect to host [public_ip] port 22: Connection timed out  lost connection"
I already run with my public ip

Comment: This is the problem. It means your local machine cannot be accessed from the Internet through ssh.